# Add a usercontrol to a panel

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a usercontrol to a panel. My code does not work:

`Panel1.Controls.Add(uc1)`

Comment: More code might be useful--is uc1 an instance of a usercontrol, or is it a class?

Comment: Where are you putting that line of code, and **how** does it not work?

Comment: uc1 is from this: VB.NET->Project->Add usercontrol / The code is into Form1_load

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an instance of the class:

```
Dim usrCntl as New uc1
Panel1.Controls.Add(userCntl)
```

But you will also have to define the properties correctly for it to view correctly.

Try using the Visual Studio IDE to place the cotrol--this will take a lot of work out of the effort.